# MySQL select best related query

Tags: mysql

```
$query1 = "select * from members where id = 5 LIMIT 1 "
```

result

```
city : 002,eye : black , car: yes,  height : 180
```

members table here :

```
|cityId |  eye  |car |height|           
|---------------|-----------|       
|001    |red    |yes | 180  |      
|002    |brown  |no  | 165  |    
|002    |black  |yes | 192  |     
|003    |green  |yes | 168  |     
|003    |brow   |no  | 180  |    
|004    |blue   |no  | 175  |
|005    |black  |no  | 177  |
|005    |black  |yes | 168  |
```

i must select new request from members table BEST RELATED with $query1 terms
how can i get ?

Comment: How are the members *related* to the query?

Comment: i need with up information, best result

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What is *best*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to decide in what order you are searching and which column has priority.
I will assume that you have a front end method such as PHP.
If you are using a form to get the data post the results to the script page.

```
$cityId=$_POST['cityId'];
$eye=$_POST['eye'];
$car=$_POST['car'];
$height =$_POST['height'];
```

If you know what the records are you are searching will match the query  you can search like this.

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `cityId`='$cityId' AND `eye`='$eye 'AND `car`='$car' AND `height`='$height'";
```

if you want to order them you need to indicate which field to order by

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `cityId`='$cityId' AND `eye`='$eye 'AND `car`='$car' AND `height`='$height'ORDER BY `cityId`DESC";
```

The more fields you search by the smaller results will be. I find the best way is to limit the search to two fields, print to screen and them select the most relevant and go from there. you could use a like search but again i find you have to limit the number of search fields to get usable results
Like query example

```
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `cityId`LIKE'%$cityId%'AND`eye`LIKE'%$eye%' ORDER BY `cityId`DESC"
```